# Is it possible to parse gps coordinates of a user's current postion to marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to set a marker so that when you load the layout it directs you to your current location based on your current gps coordinates, so i wanted to find out if it is possible to parse the current location details obtained from the gps coordinates to the marker

Comment: Yes, get your gps location in `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` of your GPS class implementing `LocationListener` and then set a marker to your map based on `loc.getLatitude() and loc.getLongitude()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. When you get location, use something like this:

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude, loc.getLongitude)));
```